# Where is the best spot to place extra files on a Wordpress install?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making changes to an existing website that is based on WordPress (some javascript add-ins and a few PHP scripts for Ajax purposes).

Is their any *proper* directory that I should place all these files? I started off putting them in a folder in the root directory called `assets`, but then decided maybe they should go with the rest of the Wordpress template and javascripts files? Or should I keep them out of the `wp-` directories, and simply keep them in the `assets` folder?

I know its a trivial question, but I like doing things right- having them in directories that make sense.

Comment: "Java" files? Javascript != Java.

Comment: Fixed.. I don't think that's worthy of a downvote though.

Comment: the downvote isn't mine... this time. I personally think it's a better question than most I see these days. :)

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep all your javascript in a folder in your theme's directory, that is `wp-content/themename/`.

Concerning Ajax, it's implementation is different in WordPress. You must add a data variable called `action` in your ajax request and then hook it to a function  in your `functions.php` file. Your ajax url should be `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` available through `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )` in PHP.

Read [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for examples.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that but seems the best way!

Answer (score 1):

If it is presentation related I believe you should place it in the corresponding theme folder. If it is a functionality you might want consider wrapping it inside a plugin and placing it in a plugin folder.

If you dont care about abstracting this change and making available to other themes, then I would just simply add it inside the theme folder. You have WP helper functions to get the web path to the current theme folder, or to include js from that folder.

Comment: It's not really functionality that requires a plugin, although I did think of this. It is just a change to the checkout page where the user has to select a suburb from a list. When they type, a list of suburbs will appear... so 2 files really- a php for the suburb lookup and a javascript that will be added to the header of the template.

Comment: Then I think you can just place it in your theme folder.

Comment: the php code you can also place in functions.php in your theme folder (http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)

Comment: Just looked and that file looks perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proper place in WordPress ecosystem is the folder `wp-content`, as this is the one that you preserve while doing WP upgrades, restorations or migrations.

In that folder, it could be part of a theme (`/themes`), a plugin (`/plugins`), an uploaded file (`/uploads`) or, if the situation requires, a custom folder (`/my-custom-content`).

### `/wp-content/themes/your-theme`

Here, all presentation related code. It's a common mistake to place general functionality code in the theme's `functions.php`. The first question to be asked before placing custom functions in this file is:
***If I change my theme, will I need this function?***

See: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

### `/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin`

Let's say you need to enqueue some CSS or Javascript files, and this should happen whatever theme is being used.
The following sample plugin will load SWFObject (bundled with WP) in the page *Map* and the front page, as both contain a SWF Flash embed. And, in the rest of the site, it will load the WebFont Loader from Google CDN and a CSS file from within the plugin folder.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: My Enqueue Plugin */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_so_16354990' );

function enqueue_so_16354990() {
    global $post;
    if( $post->post_name == 'map' || is_front_page() ) {
        // Enqueue bundled script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'swfobject' );
    }
    else {
        // Enqueue from external location
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'my-web-font', 
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.2/webfont.js', 
            array( 'jquery' ), // Dependencies
            time(), // Version, use time to prevent caching
            true // Enqueue on footer
        );  

        // Enqueue from within plugin directory 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css', plugins_url( 'css/my-plugin.css', __FILE__) );      
    }   
}
```

### `/wp-content/uploads`

Here, your theme or plugin should place all user uploaded content, so it can be managed through WP Media Library screen. And the content should survive any theme swap or plugin de-activation.

### `/wp-content/custom-folder`

Many image gallery plugins use this approach to store their custom media library.

Another use is for Mobile themes, where custom user themes are placed in this folder, so not to lose it on plugin update (as everything in the plugin or theme folders is replaced on upgrades).